# Parsing JSON result with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have an `InputStreamReader reader` that contains this JSON file:
http://barcelonaapi.marcpous.com/bus/nearstation/latlon/41.3985182/2.1917991/1.json

Also, I have a class `Station` that contains `ID, streetName, city, utmX, utmy, lat, lon` as members.

What should i do, if I want parse the JSON file with GSon, to return an `List<Station>`?

I tried this :

```
gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Station>>(){}.getType());
```

But it raised an `IllegalStateException (Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2)`.

How to extract only data which interests me (members of my `Station` class)?

Is it possible with GSon, or I need to use the JSON standard API provided by Android SDK (with `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but in this case you can't directly map to a `List<Station>` because it is wrapped in json object (2 layers deep) that also contains some other fields. That's basically also what the error is trying to tell you: you're instructing Gson to map to an array/list of items (in json: `[...]`), but instead it encountered an object (in json: `{...}`).

The quickest solution is to create a POJO that reflects this json response. For example:

```
public class Response {
    @SerializedName("code") public int mCode;
    @SerializedName("data") public ResponseData mData;
}

public class ResponseData {
    @SerializedName("transport") public String mTransport;
    @SerializedName("nearstations") public List<Station> mStations;
}
```

Now you can map the json to the above `Response` and get the `List<Station>` from the result:

```
Response response = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);
List<Station> stations = response.mData.mStations;
// do something with stations...
```

If you like to do something a little more advanced, you can take a look into writing a [custom deserialiser or type adapter](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization).

Comment: Thank you. But still not working (same Exception at line 1 column 21 path $.data)


In the JSON file, I think "nearstations" corresponds to List<Station>, not "data", no?

Comment: @Jéjé: Oops, not sure how I missed that... You're absolutely right. The stations are wrapped inside another json object. I've updated the answer to reflect that. You may want to add some `null` checks yourself.